# How to combine SUM values of different tables? (Good performance?)

Tags: mysql, performance, sum

I have following table structure, with many tables like this:

```
data_1:
+-------+--------+-------+
| views | clicks | date  |
+-------+--------+-------+
|    29 |     1  | ..... |
|   458 |     9  | ..... |
+-------+--------+-------+ 
....

data_43:
+-------+--------+-------+
| views | clicks | date  |
+-------+--------+-------+
|     0 |     0  | ..... |
|     0 |     0  | ..... |
+-------+--------+-------+ 
...
```

My question here is, how can I get all the sum values in one query?

I tried it with a simple join:

```
mysql> SELECT SUM(t1.views)  data_1_views,
              SUM(t1.clicks) data_1_clicks,
              SUM(t2.views)  data_43_views,
              SUM(t2.clicks) data_43_clicks
       FROM data_1 t1, data_43 t2;
```

But my result isn't what I expected:

```
+--------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
| data_1_views | data_1_clicks | data_43_views | data_43_clicks |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
|         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |           NULL |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
```

I expected it to be:

```
+--------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
| data_1_views | data_1_clicks | data_43_views | data_43_clicks |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
|         487  |          10   |             0 |              0 |
+--------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Anyone here who can help me with this query?
I am also interested if this is more performant than doing all this stuff in multiple queries

Comment: what result are you expecting, share it too

Comment: Should it not be SUM(t1.views) AS data_1_views, or can the AS be skipped these days?

Comment: Yeah they can be skipped, they are automatically recognized as AS statement, like in the FROM clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case multiple queries are fine especially if you are grouping many rows. There is virtually no benefit (and actually potential bugs) lumping these two tables in one query.
I would just make two queries

```
SELECT SUM(t1.views) data_1_views, SUM(t1.clicks) data_1_clicks
FROM data_1 t1 

SELECT SUM(t2.views) data_43_views, SUM(t2.clicks) data_43_clicks
FROM data_43 t2;
```

Comment: Yeah with [KingFisher's reply](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10088540/612202) I saw which overkill it would be to fill all of my columns with 'empty' values. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Union` Query.

Like below:

```
SELECT sum(t.data_1_views) as data_1_views,SUM(t.data_1_clicks) as data_1_clicks,
SUM(t.data_43_views) as data_43_views,SUM(t.data_43_views) as data_43_views
    FROM (
        SELECT SUM(t1.views)  data_1_views,SUM(t1.clicks) data_1_clicks,
        0 as data_43_views,0  as data_43_clicks
        FROM FROM data_1 as t1

        UNION

        SELECT 0 as data_1_views,0  as data_1_clicks,SUM(t1.clicks) as data_43_views, SUM(t2.clicks) 
        FROM data_43_clicks as t2 
       ) as t GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: I do understand what you are doing here, but it seems to be a lot of overkill, because there are hundred or more tables of this, so I had to fill all of sub selects with zero values. But thanks for showing me UNION.